# Compile PHP with the setting and extensions of the system one

Tags: php, php-fpm, compilation

My client has a server on Ubuntu with PHP 5.4. Currenctly I want to add PHP 5.6 + PHP-FPM to give the possibility to use a newer version of PHP. The question is :

- Is there a simple / quick way to get the system's PHP configuration to use as parameter for `./configure`

Comment: Yes, but that's not what you should be doing. Instead, you should _package_ it the same way the previous version was packaged. And of course, someone has already done this, and so you should forget about compiling it yourself and just use the appropriate PPA.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, The problem is that I want a second PHP. The 5.4 one will be used for legacy sites, the 5.6 for the new ones.